# switchLocalePath() in Nuxt error 404 layuout dont workin

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

I have Component Header and layout Error
I have Lang Switcher? but its dont workin on Error layout
this is a common problem with this plugin
I reviewed a large number of solutions, but none came up, I need to add the ability for the user to switch the language on page 404

```
<template lang="pug">
    header
        nav.navbar.navbar-expand-xl.navbar-dark.bg-dark(aria-label="Sixth navbar example")
            .container
                //- NuxtLink.navbar-brand(v-if="$i18n.locale !== 'en'", :to="localePath({ name: 'index' })")
                //-     NuxtLogo.img-fluid.w-100
                //- NuxtLink.navbar-brand(v-if="$i18n.locale === 'en'", :to="localePath('index')")
                //-     NuxtLogo.img-fluid.w-100
                
                NuxtLink.navbar-brand(:to="localePath({ name: 'index' })")
                    NuxtLogo.img-fluid.w-100
                
                button.navbar-toggler(type="button", data-bs-toggle="collapse", data-bs-target="#navbarsExample06", aria-controls="navbarsExample06", aria-expanded="false", aria-label="Toggle navigation")
                    span.navbar-toggler-icon

                #navbarsExample06.collapse.navbar-collapse
                    ul.navbar-nav.me-auto.mb-2.mb-xl-0
                        //- li.nav-item
                        //-     nuxt-link.nav-link(v-if="$i18n.locale !== 'en'", :to="localePath({ name: 'index' })") 
                        //-         span Home
                        //- li.nav-item
                        //-     nuxt-link.nav-link(v-if="$i18n.locale === 'en'", :to="localePath('index')")
                        //-         span Home
                        li.nav-item
                            nuxt-link.nav-link(:to="localePath({ name: 'index' })")
                                span Home
                        li.nav-item
                            nuxt-link.nav-link(:to="localePath({ name: 'about' })")
                                span About
                        li.nav-item
                            nuxt-link.nav-link(:to="localePath({ name: 'contacts' })")
                                span Contacts

                    ul.navbar-nav
                        li.nav-item.dropdown
                            a#lang_switcher_link.nav-link.dropdown-toggle(href="#", data-bs-toggle="dropdown", aria-expanded="false")
                                | {{$i18n.locale}}
                            ul#lang_switcher.dropdown-menu(aria-labelledby="lang_switcher_link")
                                //- li
                                //-     nuxt-link.dropdown-item(:to="switchLocalePath('en')") en
                                //- li
                                //-     nuxt-link.dropdown-item(:to="switchLocalePath('ua')") ua
                                //- li
                                //-     nuxt-link.dropdown-item(:to="switchLocalePath('ru')") ru

                                li(v-if="$i18n.locales", v-for="locale in $i18n.locales", :key="locale.code")
                                    nuxt-link.dropdown-item(:to="switchLocalePath(locale.code)") {{ locale.code }}

</template>
```